# When deploying TRAC/Subversion (SVN) on Apache with mod_wsgi, TRAC doesn't open any page at all

Tags: svn, apache, trac, mod-wsgi, mod-python

I've deployed trac using apache/mod_wsgi (no SSL) (preferable, since the
problem I'm facing with CGI is performance), and it works fine WITHOUT SVN
integration. But I actually need SVN, so when I configure the repository
path (i.e: repository_dir = c:/projects/svn/my_project) I can't even get my
project TRAC to even open any of its pages.

On Mozilla Firefox shows a white page and on MS-IE shows a 'The page cannot
be displayed' error as if the server has 'timed out'.

I've tried with mod_python (3.3.1) and the exact same problem happens. It
works fine with CGI though.

I've also tried disabeling SVN authentication, thinking it might be a
authentication conflict (I'm using Apache Basic Auth).

**Environment:**

- Win 2000 Server SP 4;
- Apache 2.2.10;
- Python 2.5.2;
- mod_wsgi revision 1018 2.3, py25_apache22;
- Trac 0.12dev;
- Subversion 1.5.3.

**Configuration files:**

- Apache httpd.conf excerpt:

> ```
> WSGIScriptAlias /trac "c:/projects/apache/trac.wsgi"
>
> <Directory c:/projects/apache>
>   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
>   Order deny,allow
>   Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

- trac.wsgi:

> ```
> import sys
> sys.stdout = sys.stderr
>
> import os
> os.environ['TRAC_ENV_PARENT_DIR'] = 'c:/projects/trac'
> os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = 'c:/projects/eggs'
>
> import trac.web.main
>
> application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
> ```

- trac.ini excerpt:

> ```
> repository_type = svn
> repository_dir = c:/projects/svn/my_project
> ```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!**

I've aligned the SVN's dlls versions used by Apache and Python to the versions avaliable here: http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100
Also followed the instructions for SVN as mentioned here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#VersionControlSystem

Step-by-step:

1. Updated my Subversion to v1.5.5, Win32 binaries for Apache 2.2.x (avaliable at http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/44589/svn-win32-1.5.5.zip).

   1. Erased my old subversion and expanded the new one;
   2. Put the new one on the system path, so that Apache can see SVN dlls;
   3. Copyied 'mod_dav_svn.so' and 'mod_authz_svn.so' to Apache's modules directory.
2. Updated the Python 2.5 bindings for Subversion on Win32 (avaliable at [http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/44591/svn-win32-1.5.5_py.zip](http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/44589/svn-win32-1.5.5.zip)).

   1. Copyied the files from '\libsvn' to 'c:\Python25\Lib...\libsvn
   2. Followed the instructions to rename the libsvn/*.dll files to .pyd (since python 2.5 no longer reads dlls);
3. Updated the Python 2.5 bindings installer for Win32 (avaliable at http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/44597/svn-python-1.5.5.win32-py2.5.exe).

   1. Installed the 'exe';
4. Restart windows.

Just for the record... it didn't exactly happend in this order, nor it happend peacefully. I've spent the whole day strugling with different .zips/.exes/.dlls/.sos. So be sure to align SVN amongst all envolved parts before giving up that sollution.

Result: It worked and my Trac/SVN performance improved dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had more problems after modifying my subversion repository. It stopped working again, with the same behaviour. So I tryied to 'resync' (since there was a log message regarding a differente revision from the cache) but nothing.

So I uninstalled everything and reinstalled it (including Apache), followed the step-by-step above PLUS:

- Run a resync (trac-admin c:\projects\myproject resync) on my project;
- Erased subversion's dlls installed by 'Python 2.5 bindings installer for Win32' from 'c:\Python25\Lib\site...\libsvn' and copyied subversion's dlls from 'c:\svn-win32-1.5.5\bin' to over it.

It worked (so far).

Any changes I'll notify.